# Не добавляется больше трех элементов в Map

Tags: java

```
class Flot {
    private Map<Integer,String> korabel = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Integer,String> func(int[] mass,String[] mass2, int Size){
        Random rand;
        for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            int size = mass[(int)(Math.random()*3)];
            String str = mass2[(int)(Math.random()*3)];
            korabel.put(size,str);
        }
        return korabel;
    }
    public void seefunc(){
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,String> mapa : korabel.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(mapa.getKey() + " " + mapa.getValue());
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Flot flot = new Flot();
        int[] mass = {30 ,50, 100};
        String[] mass1 = {"ananas", "banan", "apple"};
        int size = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        flot.func(mass,mass1,size);
        flot.seefunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Опишите, как должна работать программа

Comment: и не должно, судя по коду у Вас 3 возможных ключа `0, 1 и 2`

Comment: @AntonSorokin. В "korabel" должно добавляться Size рандомных элементов.